# Manual and automated test cases writing and storing

Tags: testing, specflow, collaboration, scenarios, testcasesource

I'm going to implement bdd specflow project in a company,
So the idea is like a manual tester will write test cases using bdd gherkin syntax, then the automation tester will understand it and automate.

so my question is if anyone can recommend a platform or a way where we can store the feature files or any type of file where gherkin syntax is possible to be written. need to give access to all team members including manual, automation, and PO too.
Excel is not considered.
and free open source tool will be great.

Comment: You tagged your question with [tag:specflow], so why not use that? You need Visual Studio and some kind of version control like Git, SVN, etc. More info: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/getting-started/en/latest/GettingStarted/Step1.html

Comment: The only downside is the Product Owner will have trouble accessing the BDD tests. For that I usually copy and paste the feature files into the descriptions of work items in whichever work item management tool you use (Azure DevOps, Atlassian Jira, GitHub, etc).

Comment: @GregBurghardt I need a test cases management platform, where all team members can see written test cases in gherkin syntax.